# Zurb Foundation 4 foundation method call contains code that conflicts with Prototype.js

Tags: jquery, magento, prototypejs, zurb-foundation, zurb-joyride

I am using Magento 1.7.2, jQuery 1.9.1 and Prototype.js 1.7, and Zurb Foundation 4 javascript plugins, namely the joyride plugin.

Well after installing the joyride plugin using the foundation.js and foundation.joyride.js files, I found that prototypejs creates a property Function.prototype.bind= function(){...}, and this is being called from foundation.js under a function called init_lib or lib_init (can't remember) that calls the bind method, probably the ecmascript5 version of bind.

When debugging the code, I saw it step into prototypejs bind from init_lib in foundation.

How can I fix this conflict without having to rename all prototypejs uses/calls of bind to some other name?

The $.foundation() method is called when the dom is ready so this is after prototypejs objects are initialized.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrototypeJS 1.7.1 handles `Function.bind` as a polyfill instead of assuming it does not exist.

In the latest version it will check if the `bind()` method is available on the Function prototype before it adds it (or replaces)

If you can't upgrade then find this block

```
return {
    argumentNames:       argumentNames,
    bind:                bind,
    bindAsEventListener: bindAsEventListener,
    curry:               curry,
    delay:               delay,
    defer:               defer,
    wrap:                wrap,
    methodize:           methodize
}
```

and replace the bind definition like this

```
     bind:                Function.prototype.bind ? Function.prototype.bind : bind,
```